# Android pass image to another xml file

Tags: android, xml, image

I have an image in my main.xml as follows

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
        android:maxHeight="70dp"
        android:maxWidth="70dp" />
```

but I need to pass it to another xml file. Is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by pass it to another xml file.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are having data reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. Exists a tag called  in android that you can "include" another android xml layout in other android xml file. I put a example using your main.xml

In layout2.xml ....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/main"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

More information about this tag, please check it out in the link below.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Thanks - but when I use this I'm assuming it takes the whole layout rather than just the ImageView? It doesn't display the image at all at the moment, but when I choose to use just the main.xml the image appears